# Powershell Script to import SYSVOL Information for ADSIEdit

Tags: active-directory, powershell

We are busy removing Windows 2012 R2 Domain controllers and in one of our sub domains we have encountered a problem where one of the previous Domain Admins removed the Domain System Volume container.

This container is required for DFSR Replication to function and as such we can not demote this domain controller.

I have done the following recovery steps

1. Checked the Deleted Objects container but could only find the DFSR-Local Settings container.
2. Restored the container and are now trying to recover the Domain System Volume container via Powershell using another Domain Controllers containers.

```perl
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$templateDomainSystemVolume = Get-ADObject "CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-LocalSettings,CN=AD1,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=xxx,DC=zzz,DC=com" `
    -Properties "msDFSR-ReplicationGroupGuid","showInAdvancedViewOnly"

$templateDomainSystemVolume

New-ADObject -Instance $templateDomainSystemVolume `
    -Name "Domain System Volume" `
    -type "msDFSR-Subscriber" `
    -path "CN=DFSR-LocalSettings,CN=AD2,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=xxx,DC=zzz,DC=jse,DC=com" `
    -OtherAttributes @{'msDFSR-MemberReference'="CN=AD2,CN=Topology,CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-GlobalSettings,CN=System,DC=resources,DC=xxx,DC=zzz,DC=com"}
```

This should create the missing container on the second specified Domain Controller using the information from the first.

The first part of the script executes perfectly. But for the second part from `New-ADObject`, I am receiving the following error when Executing the code.

```
New-ADObject : The name reference is invalid
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADObject -Instance $templateDomainSystemVolume `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo         : NotSpecified: (cn=Domain Syste...zzz,DC=com,:String) [New-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8373,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADObject
```